# A application which shows line by line sequence of the gcode

Tags: g-code, cnc

is there any application which I can load the gcode from a CNC for example and I can check line by line graphically what is going on line by line in my g-code?
I mean like the apple swift playground?

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend this one. If you are a programmer you can even edit the source code to make it more close to your needs.

https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/17424/CNC-Graphical-Backplotter

Answer (score 0):

I use the grbl-Plotter https://github.com/svenhb/GRBL-Plotter for editing GCode, simulating and controle my cnc router.